# WP7: Bringing Back App from a Tombstone State Causes App to Crash. Using a Writeablebitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I'm using a Writeablebitmap to take a screenshot of a UI element.
The code looks like this:

```
    private void Screenshot(FrameworkElement element, String fileNameLoader)
    {
        try
        {
            WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(element, null);

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            bmp.SaveJpeg(ms, (int)element.ActualWidth, (int)element.ActualHeight, 0, 100);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary();
            String filePath = string.Format(fileNameLoader);
            lib.SavePicture(filePath, ms);                
         }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            txtDebug.Text = "There was an error. Could not save. " + exception.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The issue I am having is that if I press the save button which calls the Screenshot() method, then press the Home button to tombstone the app and finally press the Back button to bring the app back, I get a screen that says "Resuming..." and the app eventually crashes.
After doing some debugging I've noticed that the error seems to be caused by the following line of code:

```
WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(element, null);
```

Replacing that line with:

```
    WriteableBitmap bmp = null;
```

saves me from the crash but my app does not work as intended (screenshot doesn't work).

Has anyone ever encountered this issue or would know how to fix it? I'm open to any work-around, as long as I can still take a screenshot of a specific UI element.

Comment: How about not catching all exceptions? Try start it with the debugger and get the error.

Comment: How complicated is your UI element? Can you run the app (w/o tombstoning) and tell us how long new WriteableBitmap() takes (use Environment.TickCount before and after to calculate, or whatever you prefer, but looking for actual time, not cpu time)

Comment: lukas, when I run it with the debugger (on either emulator or or an actual device) the app never actually crashes, it just stays on the screen that says "Resuming...". It's been going for about 5 minutes now. If I run it directly on the device (not through Visual Studio) then the "Resuming..." screen shows up for about 3-4 seconds and then the phone goes back to the start menu.

Comment: Shahar, I calculated the time using TickCount as you suggested. I ran the experiment 5 times and got an average time of 217.4ms. The UI element is pretty simple, it's two images, one taken from the camera and one from a Resource file as well as two text boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce error but you may try this:

```
private void Screenshot(FrameworkElement element, String fileNameLoader)
{
    WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap(element, null);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bmp.SaveJpeg(ms, (int)element.ActualWidth, (int)element.ActualHeight, 0, 100);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (MediaLibrary lib = new MediaLibrary())
        {
            String filePath = string.Format(fileNameLoader);
            lib.SavePicture(filePath, ms);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the behavior is the same when using this code. The problem really seems to be with the WriteableBitmap part.